# jQuery datetimepicker doesnt work.How do i use it?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to use datetimepicker but it gives error :

> TypeError: Object # has no method 'datetimepicker'

I included this scripts:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also my code :

```
   TextBox dtPicker_ = new TextBox();
   dtPicker_.ID = "dt_" + i;
   dtPicker_.CssClass = "datePicker";
   dtPicker_.Attributes.Add("checkId", "ch_" + i);

   dtPicker_.Text = cell_value_format_.Trim();
   control_ = dtPicker_;


  // ConvertToTimePicker
  string csname1 = "BindDatePickerScript";
  Type cstype = this.GetType();

  // Get a ClientScriptManager reference from the Page class.
  ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
  // Check to see if the startup script is already registered.
  if (!cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(cstype, csname1))
  {
       System.Text.StringBuilder cstext1 = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
       cstext1.Append("<script type='text/javascript'>");
       cstext1.Append("$('.datePicker').datetimepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy' });");
       cstext1.Append("</script>");

       cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, csname1, cstext1.ToString());
  }
```

Finally my "datepicker" function is working

```
cstext1.Append("$('.datePicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy' });");
```

But "datetimepicker" says not found

```
cstext1.Append("$('.datePicker').datetimepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy' });");
```

Comment: can you try removing `dateFormat ` from your code where u append datetimepicker.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/atP2P/    this is worked here but i cant do it in my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply `$(document).ready(function(){//Put your Script here});` in order to tell jQuery to load this script when all DOM in the page are ready.

Comment: i tryied it:    cstext1.Append(@"$(document).ready(function(){$('.datePicker').datetimepicker();});"); still not working

Comment: Try to run this aplication in Firefox and use Firebug to see the errors in scripts, I think `<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` is not loaded in the broswer

Comment: i loaded , but i handle an error in jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js :         $.datepicker is undefined
[Break On This Error]  

$.datepicker.formatTime = function(format, time, options) {

jquery...ddon.js (satır 943)
$(".datePicker").datetimepicker is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

<script type='text/javascript'>$('.datePicker').datetimepicker();</script>

Comment: i added "datetime" to jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.min.js again. last error is cleaned.new error : $(".datePicker").datetimepicker is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

<script type='text/javascript'>$('.datePicker').datetimepicker();</script>

Comment: i solved the problem , its my fault i had added two different scripts to same page.Masterpage and home page.thx ur helps again

Comment: You're welcome, but my advice: whenever you face an issue in jQuery use Firebug it's your hero